# Overwriting value in BehaviorSubject creates increasingly large entries

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I am using `BehaviorSubject` to store some data and grab it back at a future time. Here is some sample code to reproduce the strange issue I am encountering:

```
var subject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(undefined);

subject.next(1); // Store the value 1 into 'subject'
subject.asObservable().subscribe((data) => { console.log(data); }); 
// Output: 1

subject.next(2); // Store the value 2 into 'subject'
subject.asObservable().subscribe((data) => { console.log(data); }); 
// Output 2 \n 2 (logs twice)

subject.next(1); // Store the value 1 into 'subject'
subject.asObservable().subscribe((data) => { console.log(data); }); 
// Output: 1 \n 1 \n 1 (logs three times)
```

From what I've read online, I expected `subject.next()` to overwrite the value in the Observable, which it kind of is doing, but I don't want it to be returning these extra trailing equivalent values.

EDIT: I was unaware that subscribe() is similar to an EventListener that gets called any time the observable changes. Here's code that produces expected output:

```
var subject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(undefined);

subject.next(1); // Store the value 1 into 'subject'
subject.asObservable().subscribe((data) => { console.log(data); }); 

subject.next(2); // Store the value 2 into 'subject'
subject.next(1); // Store the value 1 into 'subject'
```

Comment: You are subscribing multiple times, so each time you subscribe, you will get an extra output in the console

Comment: In addition to what @domfx said, a BehaviourSubject also stores the last value it emitted and emits that immediately to any new subscriber, which explains the exact sequence of outputs you see.